# customizing hibernate lazy loading implementation

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading

I am having remote API call for fetching the objects. With the lazy settings, at the client when child collection with `lazy=true` setting is accessed `"org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException"` exception is thrown. I am trying to change the behavior, so that exceptions are not thrown. I found the `LoadEventListener.INTERNAL_LOAD_LAZY` in the hibernate event listeners, but could not get the much of the usage help.

Am I on the right track ?, or are there any other ways to tackle such situations?

Answer (score 0):

If you need the collection every time the entity is used, then the best approach is by configuration. By default collections are lazy-loaded. You can configure them to be eagerly-loaded (in other words: pre-loaded). Every time you ask for the entity you will always get the collection.

However, if you only need the collection some of the time (the scenario that lazy-loading is intended to address), you have a couple of options:

- Consider separating the collection(s) from the entity entirely. For
  example, instead of having a User with an Addresses collection,
  separate them out so that once you have your User, you then call
  getAddressesForUser(User) separately.
- Or write additional methods on the server-side that specifically invoke
  the collections on each entity so that they get pre-loaded before
  returning to the client. All you have to do is invoke the size()
  method on the collection. This is definitely not elegant, but works
  if you can't separate the collections from the entity for whatever
  reason.

Comment: thanks for the responce @RichW, appreciate your help. I dont want to load preload the object before sending them to client.I just want to avoid the "LazyInitializtaion" exception at the client,  and add  my customized code if such objects being accessed. Looking for the interceptor which will be called every time a lazily loaded object is accessed.

Answer (score 0):

For lazy loaded associations Hibernate will generate Proxies for lazy initialization. So, You can use `Hibenrate.isInitialize()` API to identify whether that proxy is initialized or not. So you can control the flow based on initialized proxies. If proxy not initialized those entities are not fetched yet(mean loading will happen on accessing such property values), so you can control the flow.

Comment: Appreciate your help. the thing i looking for a common place where i can use Hibenrate.isInitialize(). More like interceptor which gets called every time a proxy object is accessed.